# nodejs requirejs check if running in node

Tags: node.js, requirejs

Im working with a sample creating a simple module.  Using requirejs in node i want to check if im running in node but cant seem to get it to show that i am.  Here is my code:

```
define('defTemp', [], 
function()
{
    "use strict";

    var self = {};

    self.checkA = function()
    {
        if(typeof exports !== 'undefined' && this.exports !== exports)
            console.log('a');
        if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) 
            console.log('b');
        if (typeof exports === 'object')
            console.log('c');
        if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
            console.log('d');

    }       

    return self;
});
```

and is ran from app.js:

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs');

console.log(__dirname);

requirejs.config(
{
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    paths:
    {
        'defTemp' : 'template/defTemp'
    },
    nodeRequire: require
});


requirejs(['defTemp'], 
function(defTemp)
{
    defTemp.checkA();

});
```

None of the console (a,b,c) shows except d which makes sense because im using requirejs.  But I'm also running in node.  I want in the method checkA() to be able to tell if im running in node so I can do something different then if running in the browser.  Any help?

**Updated: 12/4/2014**
Suggestion from Leonid Beschastny is to check for window instead which work great

Comment: Checking for window is actually a good idea.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking for `window`:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  // node.js
else {
  // browser
}
```

of for `module`:

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  // node.js
else {
  // browser
}
```